# How can I assign redundant shortcuts for switching workspaces in GNOME 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I would like to bind both <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> as shortcuts to the "Switch to workspace 1" action in GNOME 3. Is there a way to do this?

I think that to achieve this there would either have to be a way to assign multiple keyboard shortcuts to the same action or there would have to be a way to switch workspaces via a command-line action (which would alet me create a shortcut for it in the "custom shortcuts" section). But I'm not sure these are possible...

Comment: +1 for `i3` style workspace binding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is a `dconf` setting and the value is an array of strings which means it accepts multiple shortcuts. You can do that via `dconf-editor` if you navigate to

*/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1*

and turn *Use default value* `OFF` then insert *Custom value*: `['<Super>Home', '<Super>1']`

[image]

---

Or if you prefer CLI you can use `dconf` or `gsettings` e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>Home', '<Super>1']"
```

Keep in mind the values must be quoted and separated by comma+space.

Answer (score 2):

Adding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and friends for workspace switching with `dconf`:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>Home', '<Super>1']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Super>2']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-3 "['<Super>3']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-4 "['<Super>4']"
```

It will not create workspaces in Gnome 3 which create them dynamically when there are windows on a previous one.

Comment: Since I return to this post once again, I'll leave a code snippet here for interested readers: assigning workspaces up to 8: `for i in $(seq 1 8); do dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-$i "['<Super>$i']"; done`. And a similar snippet for moving to nth workspace: `for i in $(seq 1 8); do dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-$i "['<Super><Shift>$i']"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my script here:

```bash
# script from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361551/how-can-i-assign-redundant-shortcuts-for-switching-workspaces-in-gnome-3
# disable unnecessary dock app launch shortcuts
# https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/super-1-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working/15187
for i in {1..9}; do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-$i "[]"; done

for i in $(seq 1 9); do dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-$i "['<Super>$i', '<Control><Alt>$i']"; done
# And a similar snippet for moving to nth workspace:
for i in $(seq 1 9); do dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-$i "['<Super><Shift>$i','<Control><Shift>$i']"; done

# in the end clean it up.
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>Home','<Super>1', '<Control><Alt>1']" 
# caused by gesttings  set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1
# replace '<Super>1'  with '<Super>0' since it always pops up nautilus.
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-1 "['<Super><Shift>Home', '<Super><Shift>1','<Control><Shift>1']"

dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-last "['<Super>End', '<Control><Alt>End']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-last "['<Super><Shift>End','<Control><Shift>End']"
```

Comment: Please explain what this script does, how it answers the question and how to use it. … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.