# Set static number of workspaces in gnome-shell with dconf

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, workspaces, dconf

How to set the behavior of `gnome-shell` workspaces (static instead of dynamic) via `dconf`?

I configured `i3` style keyboard shortcuts to [switch to specific workspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490846/47022) with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`<num>`</kbd> but `gnome-shell` creates workspaces dynamically, so I can not switch directly to 4th workspace to run programs there if workspace 3 and 4 are not created.

Comment: @don_crissti Can this extension be just a javascript that I can paste into subdir of my home folder?

Comment: Found https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/12/static-workspaces/ that says that extension is not required anymore and GNOME Tweak Tool can be used. Does it save configuration with `dconf`?

Comment: Oh, my bad... looks like somewhere along the way they've decided to support this via `dconf` keys.

Answer (score 16):

As you've found out, you can do this via `tweak-tool`:

[image]

and indeed, the changes are now done in the `dconf` database so if you prefer doing it in terminal you need to toggle `dynamic-workspaces` to `false` and set the desired `num-workspaces` so either use the low-level `dconf` tool:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/dynamic-workspaces false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/num-workspaces 4
```

or the high-level schema-aware `gsettings` tool:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 4
```

Altering those keys can be done also via `dconf-editor`.

Comment: That might work but in Debian-10 "Buster" the deconf edit does not include setting the number of workspaces. It used to be a Gnome "settings